# Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges, then also $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, with $a_n > 0, b_n > 0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ be two series with $a_n > 0, b_n > 0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}, \forall n \geq n_0$$

Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges, then also $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges.

---

My attempt:

We can rearrange

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}} \leq \frac{a_{n}}{b_n} \implies \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} \leq \frac{a_{n-1}}{b_{n-1}} \leq ... \leq \frac{a_0}{b_0}$$

This implies $a_n \leq \frac{a_0}{b_0}b_n$.

We know $b_n$ converges, and $\frac{a_0}{b_0}$ is a constant. So that means $a_n$ also has to converge due to $a_n \leq \frac{a_0}{b_0}b_n$.

---

First, does this count as a proof or is it somehow wrong or missing something ?

Second, this is an exercise they gave us. As hints to solve it, they gave us this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \cdot \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}}$$ and
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+1} \cdot \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n}}$$

Now, the thing is, I actually don't see how they expect us to solve this using those hints. So I don't know if what I did above is completely wrong, or if there is another way to prove that using those hints, but I wouldn't see how.

Comment: Your argument is essentially correct except that you took $n_0=0$. That hint does not make sense to me.

Comment: @geetha290krm Do we need to take $n_0 = 1$ ?

Comment: No. $n_0$ is given to you.  You get $\frac {a_n}{b_n}\leq \frac {a_{n_0}} {b_{n_0}}$ for $n \geq n_0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Uh I see, in fact. But $a_{n_0}$ and $b_{n_0}$ are still just "constants", right ? So the argument still holds ?

Comment: @geetha290krm I'm also confused by their hints, they also wrote $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n < +\infty$ but this seems kind of obvious if $b_n$ converges, so I don't see why they write it as a hint.